# How to deploy Google Cloud NLP with python

Tags: google-cloud-automl

I have my model trained using GCP's auto ML system, and am ready to deploy it using Python. In the sample code provided by Google, they are importing several libraries:

```py
import sys

from google.api_core.client_options import ClientOptions
from google.cloud import automl_v1
from google.cloud.automl_v1.proto import service_pb2
```

And I cannot find where I can get these libraries. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are referencing the [official Python Client Library](https://googleapis.dev/python/automl/latest/index.html) for AutoML. You can download and install it by doing:

**Mac**

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv <your-env>
source <your-env>/bin/activate
<your-env>/bin/pip install google-cloud-automl
```

**Windows**

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv <your-env>
<your-env>\Scripts\activate
<your-env>\Scripts\pip.exe install google-cloud-automl
```